# Using find, creating rows, manipulating data

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to using VBA and have spent a good while watching yt vids and looking online at pdf's etc. but not making any headway. I have included two screen clippings with generic data to help understanding. My problem is:

1. Find instances where there is an 'Install' printed in Schedule tab
2. Move left a cell and take the name of the corresponding Install
3. Search for that corresponding name in the Cables Detailed tab
4. Find how many Cables with the corresponding name there is
5. Create the number of rows needed below the corresponding name in the Schedule Tab. Ex. Cable D would need 4 new rows inserted below it in the Schedule tab.
6. Insert data 2,3,4 from Cables Detailed Tab into the new cells for the corresponding Cable in the Schedule tab.
7. Move on to the next instance of 'Install' and complete the same process
8. The programme also needs to mitigate for instances where it will come across an 'Install' but there is no data in the Cables Detailed tab for this.

I have tried using record macros but I do not think it is possible to perform the actions I need using this, it is too complex. I have done a bit of MATLAB before so have some basic programming skills but not very hot on VBA.

Any help or links to guides that I would find handy would be much appreciated.

Cheers

**Schedule Tab**

[image]

**Cables Detailed Tab**

[image]

Comment: For point 1, see how to use [.Find and .FindNext](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/). For Point 2, use `Offset()` after you have found the cell. For point 3, again use `.Find` Start with this first and then we will go to the other points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below code. It should cover all of your bullets, however I was not 100% sure what you would like to achieve regading 8th.

```
Sub Cables()
    Dim wsSchedule As Worksheet
    Dim wsCabDet As Worksheet
    Set wsSchedule = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Schedule")
    Set wsCabDet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cables Detailed")
    Dim RowCount As Integer
    RowCount = wsSchedule.Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rCables As Range
    Dim rCable As Range
    Set rCables = wsCabDet.Range("a2", wsCabDet.Range("a1048576").End(xlUp))
    Dim CableFound As Boolean
    For i = RowCount To 2 Step -1
        If wsSchedule.Range("b" & i) = "Install" Then
            CableFound = False
            For Each rCable In rCables
                If rCable = wsSchedule.Range("a" & i) Then
                    With wsSchedule.Range("b" & i + 1)
                        .EntireRow.Insert
                        .Offset(-1, -1).Value = rCable
                        .Offset(-1, 1).Value = rCable.Offset(0, 1)
                        .Offset(-1, 2).Value = rCable.Offset(0, 2)
                        .Offset(-1, 3).Value = rCable.Offset(0, 3)
                    End With
                    CableFound = True
                End If
            Next rCable
            If Not CableFound Then
                With wsSchedule.Range("b" & i)
                    .Offset(0, 1).Value = "No cable found"
                    .Offset(0, 2).Value = "No cable found"
                    .Offset(0, 3).Value = "No cable found"
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Your section below solves point 8 that I have. Thank you for your answer it works a treat.             If Not CableFound Then
                With wsSchedule.Range("b" & i)
                    .Offset(0, 1).Value = "No cable found"
                    .Offset(0, 2).Value = "No cable found"
                    .Offset(0, 3).Value = "No cable found"
                End With
            End If

Comment: That's great! Glad I could help :)